# How to use ScaNN on the tflite mission

Tags: java, android, tflite, scann

How can I use ScaNN algorithm to create tflite model

How can I use ScaNN algorithm to create tflite modell
How can I use ScaNN algorithm to create tflite modell
How can I use ScaNN algorithm to create tflite modell
How can I use ScaNN algorithm to create tflite modell
How can I use ScaNN algorithm to create tflite modell
How can I use ScaNN algorithm to create tflite modell
How can I use ScaNN algorithm to create tflite modell
How can I use ScaNN algorithm to create tflite modell
How can I use ScaNN algorithm to create tflite modell

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.